# mod_rewrite old urls with parameters to new URL's, but using the old parameters with the new URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a tricky rewrite situation where I am needing to rewrite old URL's that have parameters, to new URL's, but at the same time appending the parameters of the old (now invalid) URL to this new URL.

Example: An old link of ring-details.php?product=**MQ==**&hash=376FGE367ER872CBD5 will now become rings/ring-detail/**23**.htm where the number 23 is actually the base64_decoded value of the product URL above.

So essentially I need to do this:

- Check if the page being requested is ring-details.php and that there
  is a parameter 'product' present. Hash is no longer used.
- Take the product parameters value (MQ==), base64_decode it
- Append the decoded value to the new URL: rings/ring-detail/$1.htm
  where $1 is the decoded product URL parameter.

I am not asking to be spoon fed, but any hints or good resources would be great. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot decode Base64 in .htaccess/mod_rewrite. But you could make a workaround via PHP.

So you have to catch the old URL and rewrite it to the PHP file, which decodes Base64 and redirects to the new URL.

Content of `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ring-details\.php$ redirect.php?product=%1 [L]
```

Content of `redirect.php`:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/rings/ring-detail/'.intval(base64_decode($_GET['product'])).'.htm', true, 301);
?>
```

But actually you could modify `ring-details.php` instead and add this code at the very top:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['product'])){
    header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/rings/ring-detail/'.intval(base64_decode($_GET['product'])).'.htm', true, 301);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: You "kind of" can (RewriteMap, **prg:** type) -- but that pretty much the same as your solution, just "different flavour". I personally would go this PHP way.

Comment: @Floern - Thank you! That was a very well considered and well though out solution, and the up side to doing it your way, is that I can still query the database, get the products title, and append it to the URL to have a more description 301 redirect URL. Thank you.

Comment: @Floern I spoke too soon. It seems now that even requests for valid NEW urls like /rings/some-ring/23.htm are also being redirected to the redirect php script, even though their rules are specified AFTER the one above?

Comment: @Floern - I sorted it out by checking that the old URL has the parameter product AND hash, because new ones don't have hash any longer, it was an OKAY check. My Rule: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} product=(.*)&hash=(.*)
RewriteRule ring-details\.php 301\.php?t=ring&p=%1 [L]`